# Store Bitmap Screenshot in Android Cache

Tags: android

Can someone please help me make my code below store to cache rather than my sd card.  I am taking a screenshot of my application to use for sharing on social media.

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card
                String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

                // create bitmap screen capture
                Bitmap bitmap;
                View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                OutputStream fout = null;
                imageFile = new File(mPath);

                try {
                    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
                    fout.flush();
                    fout.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And here is my Social Media code to share the screenshot:

```
Intent socialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                    socialIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));

                    socialIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    socialIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(socialIntent, "How do you wanna share?"));
```

Comment: Use Context.getCacheDir() instead of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I don't believe that I can use cache with my scenario. Only my application would have access to this storage and I need social medias to have access to this storage and it doesn't and can't.

Comment: "I need social medias to have access to this storage and it doesn't and can't" - that is correct but your question was about NOT using the SD card. If you want other apps/activities etc to access the file then it MUST be saved in external storage (the SD card for example). External storage doesn't apply file-system permissions but internal memory does.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a good idea to store bitmap in cache because there will be memory leak issue. But, you can do following thing to store bitmap in cache.

> ```
> static HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
> ```

to store bitmap into cache

> cache.put(filename, bmp);

later, to retrieve bitmap from cache use following code,

```
    if(cache.containsKey(filename)){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(filename));
    }
```